# Upgrading "icu" pacman package

Tags: archlinux

Today I tried to upgrade the "icu" pacman package, because I need it for NodeJS to work.
After I installed the newest version my system completely broke, I can't even start it up anymore.
Does anybody know how to fix the problem with Node or how to correctly upgrade the "icu" package?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't upgrade individual packages. Instead, you should upgrade the entire system. The reason for this is that the dependencies that exist between packages will break sooner or later if you perform partial upgrades.

If you can't boot your system any more, try booting on the installation media, mount the installed disk, [arch-chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch-chroot) into it and run `pacman -Syu`.

The proper way to upgrade Arch linux is described here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Upgrading_the_system